my spring sproject throws error, it said SecurityConfiguration couldn't be found
I import every libaries. btw I forked it github from my teacher's repository, but my teacher said he didn't have any error.
this is error :

Parameter 0 of method securityFilterChain in uz.smartup.academy.hibernateadvanced.config.SecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.`

here is my code :
package uz.smartup.academy.hibernateadvanced.config;
`
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager detailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    
        detailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("Select username, password, enabled FROM user WHERE username = ?");
        detailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("Select username, role WHERE username = ?");
    
        return detailsManager;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain( HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(authRegistry ->
                        authRegistry
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,  "/web/instructors", "/web/instructors/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/web/instructors/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/web/instructors/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/web/instructors/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/web/students/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "INSTRUCTOR")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/web/students/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "INSTRUCTOR")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/web/students/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "INSTRUCTOR")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/web/students/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/web/courses/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "INSTRUCTOR", "STUDENT")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/web/courses/*").hasAnyRole("INSTRUCTOR")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/web/courses/*").hasAnyRole("INSTRUCTOR")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/web/reviews/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "INSTRUCTOR", "STUDENT")
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/web/reviews/*").hasAnyRole("STUDENT")
                                .requestMatchers("/access-denied").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                        configurer.accessDeniedPage("/access-denied"))
                .formLogin(form ->
                        form.loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                                .permitAll())
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
    
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        httpSecurity.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}`

I added @EnableWebSecurity to top of SecurityConfiguration, and @Autowired next to HttpSecurity. But it doesn't work. when i added @EnabledWebSecurity, I got another error.

"when i added @EnabledWebSecurity, I got another error" That was the right thing to do. Just because something results in a different error doesn't mean it was the wrong solution. It was the right solution, and you just need something else. You need to show that other error.

this is another error while adding @EnableWebSecurity : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-29T13:53:20.139+05:00 ERROR 10300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Edit the question with the full stack trace
